# There an error when archive Flutter app to submit to Apple store

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a project written in Flutter[image: error message]. When the archive is about to be uploaded to the appstore, an error message is encountered as shown. Can anyone help me know where this error is, and how to solve it? (because when I debug there is no error at all)

I really don't know how to fix that. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Temporary workaround.

1.Download [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/transporter/id1450874784) app from App Store into your Mac

2.Extract the ipa from Xcode Organizer

3.Choose ipa in Transport

4.Deliver